# Multiple and different counters in one activity

Tags: java, android

Basically I need a TableLayout which contains multiple rows and in every row there must be a different counter (which I can add or subtract 1 by pressing one of the two buttons in the row).

Here you can see a clear example:

**content_main.xml**

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="Pizza Margherita"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="-"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/minusButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Button
                android:text="+"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/plusButton"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_column="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="Pizza Salame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="-"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/minusButton2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_width="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/result2"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Button
                android:text="+"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/plusButton2"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_column="1" />

        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I have no idea how to work on **MainActivity.java**. 
By far I tried to implement an array (without success) and write a separate class for every single counter (but it resulted too redundant).

Any tips?

Comment: Hint: without you showing more code, not much will happen here. We are not a "me vision but no idea, please fill the gap service". Besides: you might want to give your buttons names that are more distinct. Dont call things buttonp or buttonm, why not call them minusButton or plusButton?!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, I'd suggest to you to implement a custom view logic for your counter and and adapter to turn it more scalable.

Basically you'll have:

- counter_layout.xml - Declare the components
- CounterView.java - Inflate the layout and control the logic of counter
- CounterAdapter.java - Instantiate a multiple intances of a CounterView

Then, you could use an ListView in your Activity that will show the adapter's content.

Ofcourse that you will need manage the state of each CounterView. But it is easy and maybe it'd be a next step of your project.